# Unable to load asset images

Tags: flutter

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      //il flex è di default quindi prende 1/6 della pagina
      child: Column(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(child: Image.asset("assets\images\logo.png"))
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      //prende 5/6 della pagina
      flex: 5,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)));
 }
```

//
This is my code as you can see I have entered everything right, only that in the terminal on output it does not give me any kind of error while if I load the google page, I get the error I wrote in the title now I am attaching the screenshot of the page.

[error of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z0aC.png)
//I also checked the pubspec.yamal but theoretically it is right I also leave you the one below

pubspec.yamal

assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/icons/

//now I am also attaching the screenshot of the folders

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC9DV.png)

Comment: Try changing your slash type from `assets\images\logo.png` to `assets/images/logo.png`

Comment: I tried but it still keeps giving this error: Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/assets/images/logo.png" (404)

Comment: Did you check the extension of the file? once i spent a good few hours trying to solve a error like this and my image name was "image.jpg" and it was written "image.png" on my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `/` instead of `\` when you enter the path for image.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      //il flex è di default quindi prende 1/6 della pagina
      child: Column(
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"))
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      //prende 5/6 della pagina
      flex: 5,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)));
 }
```

Comment: I tried but it still keeps giving this error: Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/assets/images/logo.png" (404)

Comment: Did you detach the app and try again. Also `"assets/assets/images/logo.png" (404)` ? It should be `"assets/images/logo.png" (404)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes now go, thanks a lot I put your answer as right